# why this query repeat the first and the last name in this code

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

when i run this query i have the result in the right why but name and the father name repeated in all lines . i want it just one time . i put for example the 1773 id number to test it .

```
<?


                $query = mysql_query("
                                        SELECT *
                                        FROM students,grades,subjects
                                        WHERE
                                        students.id_students = grades.id_students AND 
                                        grades.id_subjects = subjects.id_subjects AND 
                                        students.id_students = 1773 ;




                                         ");

                while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)

                    ){
                    $id_students = $row['id_students'];
                    $firstname = $row['firstname'];
                    $surename = $row['surename'];
                    $father = $row['father'];
                    $marks = $row['marks'];
                    $class = $row['class'];
                    $name = $row['name'];


                 echo "$firstname" . "$surename"; 
                 echo "$marks" ." " . "$name" ; 
                 echo "<br>";
                 echo "$class";

                    }

?>
```

Comment: you didn't output `$father` at all

Answer (score 0):

Use just one table in `FROM` clause and for others use `JOIN`.

```
SELECT s.*, 
       g.*, 
       su.*
FROM students s
JOIN grades g
    ON g.id_students = s.id_students
JOIN subjects su
    ON su.id_subjects = g.id_subjects
WHERE s.id_students = 1773
```

Comment: @FuadBro: hm, probably misunderstood your question. So, what is current output and what the output you want?

Comment: i am sorry may be i don't explain it very well so .i want to put in this fist like the name and the father name after the i want to put the subject and the mark of this subject and there is many subject . just that

Comment: @FuadBro: sorry, still not understandable. Try it once again, please.

Comment: ok . i want this result at the end  : 
Foda bro 
infomatic 70
biography 120 
itd 30 
....

foda bro = name of students 
and (infomatic ,biography, itd ) = subjects 
and ( 70 , 120 , 30 marks ) 

just that

Answer (score 0):

Due to the previous answer which will be deleted, this should be what you need. `$data` array is the same as you get from database.

```
<?php

$data = array(
    0 => array(
        'id_students' => 1,
        'firstname' => 'Fuad',
        'surename' => 'Bro',
        'father' => 'fathers name',
        'marks' => 30,
        'class' => 1,
        'name' => 'itd'
    ),

    1 => array(
        'id_students' => 1,
        'firstname' => 'Fuad',
        'surename' => 'Bro',
        'father' => 'fathers name',
        'marks' => 120,
        'class' => 1,
        'name' => 'biography'
    ),

    2 => array(
        'id_students' => 1,
        'firstname' => 'Fuad',
        'surename' => 'Bro',
        'father' => 'fathers name',
        'marks' => 120,
        'class' => 1,
        'name' => 'informatic'
    )
);

$last_name = '';

foreach ($data as $row) {
    if ($row['firstname'] != $last_name) {
        echo '<b>' . $row['firstname'] . ' ' . $row['surename'] . ' (father: ' . $row['father'] . ')</b><br>';
    }

    echo 'class: ' . $row['class'] . '<br>';
    echo 'subject name: ' . $row['name'] . '<br>';
    echo 'marks: ' . $row['marks'] . '<br><br>';

    $last_name = $row['firstname'];
}

/*
    output:

    Fuad Bro (father: fathers name) -- name and father's name just once
    class: 1
    subject name: itd
    marks: 30

    class: 1
    subject name: biography
    marks: 120

    class: 1
    subject name: informatic
    marks: 120
*/

?>
```

Comment: @FuadBro: and the SQL query as I wrote in my previous answer will be faster than your original, use that too :-)